# Can I draw rectangle in XML?

Tags: android, xml, draw

I wonder if I can draw rectangle in XML.
I know how to draw using drawRect method programmatically.

Comment: saying XML means all and nothing, i.e. anything...

Comment: What's the purpose of using XML? drawRect works on Canvas, which is usually used in creating custom views.

Comment: I completely diagree with @Creator, we rarely use Canvas unless it is for something a little more complex. The XML version makes it easy to change the background across the entire app for particular UI elements , as a result of the attributes being defined in one location.

Comment: @GrahamSmith I asked for the purpose, so that I can get to know what he wanted to do with this. You might rarely use a Canvas, I used it many times developing Games. Nothing to agree or disagree here.

Comment: @creator sorry I think I misinterpreted the tone of comment as "why would you bother?". My apologies.

Comment: you can easily draw rectangle by making resource file

Answer (score 268, accepted):

Yes you can and here is one I made earlier:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
</shape>
```

You can create a new XML file inside the drawable folder, and add the above code, then save it as rectangle.xml.

To use it inside a layout you would set the `android:background` attribute to the new drawable shape. The shape we have defined does not have any dimensions, and therefore will take the dimensions of the View that is defined in the layout.

So putting it all together:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/myRectangleView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"/>
```

Finally; you can set this rectangle to be the background of any View, although for ImageViews you would use `android:src`. This means you could use the rectangle as the background for ListViews, TextViews...etc.

Comment: How would somebody go about making it so that the color could be set from the android layout where we make the <View ?

Comment: I think you can't add id for it

Comment: how to change stroke color programatically?

Answer (score 37):

Create `rectangle.xml` using Shape Drawable Like this put in to your **Drawable** Folder...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
   <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
   <corners android:radius="12px"/> 
   <stroke  android:width="2dip" android:color="#000000"/>  
</shape>
```

put it in to an `ImageView`

```
<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/rectimage" 
android:layout_height="150dp" 
android:layout_width="150dp" 
android:src="@drawable/rectangle">
</ImageView>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 24):

Quick and dirty way:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/colored_bar"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="@color/bar_red" />
```

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="15dp"
                        android:layout_height="15dp"
                        android:background="#3fe1fa" />

                    <TextView
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="1700 Market Street"
                        android:id="@+id/textView8" />
                </TableRow>
```

output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:radius="0.1dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />

    <solid android:color="#Efffff" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#25aaff" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

create resource file in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#3b5998" />
<cornersandroid:radius="15dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Create a rectangle vector asset then //Put this code inside the rectangle drawable file and use this drawable(rectangle) as background.i,e -  android:background="@drawable/baseline_rectangle_24"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#C4C4C4" />
        <padding android:left="2dp"
            android:top="2dp"
            android:right="2dp"
            android:bottom="2dp" />
        <corners android:radius="15dp" />
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).