# Insert something inside a view android

Tags: android, android-layout

What i would like to do is draw a rectangle and put some dynamic text inside,this is possible?

I guess isnt,but there are any way to resolve this??

Anyway im drawing the rectangle using this example here..
[rectangle -example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124919/can-i-draw-rectangle-in-xml)

Comment: You will have to be a lot more precise on what you want to achieve.  For example, why isn't a TextView with a border good enough?

Comment: I didnt know that a border was possible in android :O Well,maybe that is my solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you are giving is rather static. You could also go for a more dynamic approach where you override the onDraw method of a View:

```
public class MyView extends View {
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawRect(10, 10, 10, 10, p);
        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawText("Ohai!", 0, 5, 20, 20, p);
    }
}
```

You just then put this View on your panel where you want it. There are of course even more methods to use for this, just have a look at the [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) class

Or you could of course just some kind of TextView you can customize (add some borders etc).