# How to create a rectangle over camera preview

Tags: android-camera, drawrectangle

I am working on face recognition project. I want to create a rectangle over camera preview so that a person can adjust his/her face in that box before taking an image. Is it possible with any method? I have searched but haven't got any help of rectangle, people have written text and have used images.

Comment: Use an image which is a [rectangle drawable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124919/can-i-draw-rectangle-in-xml) with transparent filling