# EditText does not show its full layout

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have the following EditText .

```
          <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" />
```

For this edittext I have got the following layout .

[image]

But I want to get the edittext like following :

[image]

How to get the edittext like above ?

Comment: you can create using XML. check out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646415/how-to-create-edittext-with-rounded-corners    and     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124919/can-i-draw-rectangle-in-xml

Comment: have look on my edit answer it solve your problem i checked it ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a drawable background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/very_light_grey"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/grey"/>
</shape>
```

Change your edittext to

```
<EditText
  android:background="@drawable/background"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:paddingLeft="60dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'color' with value '@android:color/
 very_light_grey').

Comment: add colors with name your_background_color to your colors.xml file and change it to @colors/your_background_color.

Answer (score 0):

you can set padding in edit Text.

```
android:padding="10dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Its basically goes with android version of the device.Earlier version of android EditText has somewhat similar kind look as you looking for. But with latest you will get line. I would like suggest go change edit text theme or background to serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Set background of edittext in xml using

```
android:background="Your Color Code"
```