# How to create square button in android for background?

Tags: android

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEs7C.png)

I want to create square shape in background. Android studio shape doesn,t support square.How to create manually in border.xml?

Here is my code

border.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="#9294a3" />

    <stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#c2bbbb" />

    <corners android:radius="2dp" />

</shape>
```

my.xml

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="#9294a3">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="#c2bbbb"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout
```

Comment: just give height and width same to button.

Comment: Please check one of my so [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10125179/392506)

Comment: <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

Comment: @Raj. It shows in rectangle border.How to make square?

Comment: What is Your Text length approx?

Comment: @kevanaghera. When I set same height and  width in textview, it show padding issue. I want to show text  "2" in center in square border.

Comment: u want "2" in centre of textview border right?

Comment: @Raj  I am using 40 dp width and height. and it shows padding issue. I want to show text  "2" in center in square border.

Comment: set Textview width and height wrapcontent instead of  40dp

Comment: @kevanaghera . yes.

Comment: @Raj I have added image.check it.I want to show text in center. When I  change screen size it show padding issue.

Comment: image size match parent replace with wrap content    not work then attach the layout code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/input_name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:direction="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Button like this[image]

**xml**

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
```

**Style** (drawable/border.xml)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorGray"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/colorBlack"
                android:width="4dp" />
            <!--corners allow us to make the rounded corners button-->
            <corners android:radius="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should specify shape='Rectangle' for square it will be better.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="10dp"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="#9294a3" />

<stroke
android:width="2dp"
android:color="#c2bbbb" />

<corners android:radius="2dp" />
```